# Show cookies in php

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I want to show javascript variables in php and i used cookies to do that, but I run this gets some errors. This is that errors

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant latitude - assumed 'latitude' in C:\wamp\www\varCoo.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: latitude in C:\wamp\www\varCoo.php on line 16 

Notice: Use of undefined constant longitude - assumed 'longitude' in C:\wamp\www\varCoo.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: longitude in C:\wamp\www\varCoo.php on line 17
```

Whats Wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    var x = -40;
    var y = 72;
    document.cookie = latitude + "=" + x;
    document.cookie = longitude + "=" + y;
</script>
<?php
    echo $_COOKIE[latitude];
    echo $_COOKIE[longitude];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just as the notices say and cookies are not recognized in echos unless they have been checked if they are set/not empty and will throw that error on initial page load.

Answer (score 2):

You can write in this way

```
  <script>
    var x = -40;
    var y = 72;
    document.cookie = 'latitude' + "=" + x;
    document.cookie = 'longitude' + "=" + y;
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['latitude']) && isset($_COOKIE['longitude']))
  {  
     echo $_COOKIE['latitude'];
     echo $_COOKIE['longitude'];
  }else{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.innerHTML = x +'<br>'+y; // or in some element as you like
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array keys must be in quotes (if you want that notice to go away).

```
<?php
    echo $_COOKIE['latitude'];
    echo $_COOKIE['longitude'];
?>
```

FYI, your sample script won't work anyway as cookie data is not available to PHP until they are set and a new request has been made.

Comment: I added quotes but still remains two errors, How to make cookie data available to php?

Comment: You need to set the cookies in javascript and then make a new page request to your php script, probably by using window.location to redirect there.

Comment: That mean can't I do it in same page? Would you please give me an example for that (to send javascript variable to php in same page by cookies)

Comment: i guess it is down voted is because key value can be without quotes (if no constant is defined)

Comment: @FerozAkbar but that doesn't solve the problem of the notice. It works but a notice is still thrown.

Comment: @Nishan256 You can but the cookies must be set *before* you make a http request to your PHP script otherwise they will not be available to your PHP code.

Comment: @JohnConde even if the key is in quotes ,you'l get undefined index, right?

Comment: Only if they try to access those values before they are set which is what we're discussing above

Answer (score 0):

Now it works!!!, I changed latitude+"="+x to "latitude="+x; and echo $_COOKIE['latitude']. And longitude too

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    var x = -40;
    var y = 72;
    document.cookie = "latitude=" + x;
    document.cookie = "longitude=" + y;
</script>
<?php
    echo $_COOKIE['latitude'];
    echo $_COOKIE['longitude'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `first check with php if(isset($_COOKIE['lat']) && isset($_COOKIE['lan']))
{ //echo $cookie
}else{ ?>document.body.innerHTML = x +'<br>'+y; <?php }`